# jQuery Equal Heights of Divs

Tags: html, jquery, css, jquery-events

I have two columns that have draggable and droppable divs within them. I used this code:

```
//Equal Height Divs
        function equalHeight( group ) {
            var tallest = 0;
            group.each(function() {
                var thisHeight = $(this).height();
                if(thisHeight > tallest) {
                    tallest = thisHeight;
                }
            });
            
            group.each(function() {
                $(this).css( "min-height", tallest );
            } );
        }
```

To make sure that as more divs are added to one column and that columns height gets larger so will the height of the second column.

However I don't seem to know how to reverse this so that if I remove things from one column and the div height of both columns should get smaller. I know that I have over-complicated this so any help to sort out my confusion here would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add `$(this).css("height", "");`, to reset the CSS height attribute, so that the height won't be greater than necessary. Without a set `height` property, the element will shrink to the minimum height:

```
    function equalHeight( group ) {
        var tallest = 0;
        group.each(function() {
            $(this).css({height:"", "min-height":""});
            var thisHeight = $(this).height();
            if(thisHeight > tallest) {
                tallest = thisHeight;
            }
        });

        group.each(function() {
            $(this).css( "min-height", tallest );
        } );
    }
```

Comment: Won't this just set the height to 'tallest', which is still the same height as before?

Comment: No, `$(this).css("height","")` resets the height variable, so that the element shrinks to the minimum size.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand your question only to an extent. If you are trying to set the height of elements with the height of the highest element, you can use this code. It is assuming that the elements that you are working on has same class.

```
var maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, $('.common_classname').map(function() {
                return $(this).height();
        }).get());

$('.common_classname').height(maxHeight);
```

Comment: Yes this works in order for two divs to have the same height as the highest one. However when I take things out of one div, I need the two columns to decrease in size?

Comment: You need an event listener, like when you remove things out of one div, you need to run this piece of code to re-calculate and set the height.